# Linux: How to mount a drive from command line

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-mint, mount, executable

I normally mount my drives just by opening it from filesystem. It automatically mount when I open/click on a drive. But I wanted to mount a drive from command line. I did ran this command

```
sudo mount -o exec /media/bcc/Other
```

but I get this error

```
mount: /dev/sda9 already mounted or /media/bcc/Other busy
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda9 is already mounted on /media/bcc/Other
```

This error show when I already mounted the Study drive by opening it from filesystem. But if I unmount the drive and then run the same command I get this error

```
mount: can't find /media/bcc/Study in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

How can I mount a drive from command line?

I am using windows filesystem for mounted drive.

This is my `/etc/fstab` file

```
    # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=2938ed95-8fbb-4400-9caa-d5311b3ae214 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=1CB9-3478  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=96753f71-252e-4e1b-8796-086be5fc29da none            swap    sw              0       0
```

and `/etc/mtab` file

```
/dev/sda11 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars efivarfs rw 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /run/user tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755 0 0
none /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw 0 0
/dev/sda2 /boot/efi vfat rw 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
systemd /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,user=bcc 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the mount command with just one argument `/media/bcc/Other` ( the `-o exec` is an option), that argument needs to be listed in `/etc/fstab` for mount to find where to mount (if you specify a device) or what to mount (if you specify a directory). If you don't want/have that you need to specify both the device and where to mount it:

```
sudo mount device dir
```

as you can see in the man pages (`man mount`). If you specify a device, the directory has to exist.

What is a bit worrying is that your /etc/fstab indicates that (during installation) `sda9` was swap device, and now you seem to be using it for data. You should probably update your swap settings in your `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still im confused since I am totally new in Linux world. Lots of things seems just magic. Anyway, what I understand is if I want to mount "Other" device then I have to write '/media/bcc/Other' in etc/fstab and then after my pc starts I have t write  command in command line 'sudo mount /media/bcc/Other'. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @user3128796 Yes you can write a full like in `/etc/fstab`. Use `man fstab` to read about the 6 fields and what values they have, there you also add `auto` or `default` to the 4th field to have the drive be mounted on startup . After you do that you can just use `mount /media/bcc/Other`. Without that you need to do `mount -o exec /dev/sda9 /media/bcc/Other` (adjust `sda9` to the right device (alternatively use its UUID or LABEL).